# autoML unable to download model using google cli command

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, automl

It's my first time working with tensor flow and I'm trying to download an image classification model I created using the autoML vision UI. I'm following along with the tutorial here: 
https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/tensorflow-js-tutorial?hl=en_US

I try to copy the command from autoML's UI to download the exported model to my pc inside my desktop directory just so I can play around with it but I always get an error that the url is invalid.

(I have replaced the bucket and model name for privacy in this question)

autoML provides me with the following cli command:

```
$ gsutil cp -r gs://bucket/model-export/icn/tf_js-xxxxxx_20200508044511-2020-05-08T22:27:02.706Z/./download_dir
```

I have modified it as the tutorial notes that the attached timestamp will make the url invalid

```
gsutil cp -r gs://bucket/model-export/icn/tf_js-xxxxxx_20200508044511/ ./
```

but unfortunately I always get the error:

```
CommandException: No URLs matched: gs://bucket/model-export/icn/tf_js-xxxxxx_20200508044511/
```

I'm wondering if anyone else has come across this issue and can point out whatever obvious mistake I am making.

thanks :)

Comment: it looks like the gs to which it is pointint just does not exist. just go to google storage and copy the exact path where the model was exported

Comment: Thanks @albesa I’ll give that a try